# create account in aws cognito user pool for facebook sign up

Tags: javascript, facebook-login, amazon-cognito

recently I am learning AWS cognito, and I want to allow users to use their facebook accounts to sign up to my website, and AWS cognito can add this new user to the user pool, so that I don't need to manage separate user directories. Is there any way to do it? I have tried many tutorials but none of them work.

And, I am also looking for how to link the facebook account with an existing account in the user pool, any instructions or sample projects will be helpful. I have been spending a lot of time on these problems, that's so annoying, I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no exact answer to this since the documentation provided by AWS regarding AWS Cognito has a tendency of being outdated and inaccurate.

There is a solution (somehow), if you look here: 
https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js

Comment: It is a link only answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know how to link a facebook account with my existing app account? Just like a user have to create his account for my app, and after that, he connects it with his facebook account, so he can use his facebook account to login in and use the services of my app.